# Spring Boot @Transaction not rolling back on RuntimeException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-jdbc

I have a spring boot application that is using spring-boot-starter-jdbc, Java 8 and MySQL with InnoD. The application isn't rolling back Runtime Exceptions, even when I do this:

```
throw new RuntimeException("Rolling back");
```

I am configuring my Transactions like this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
```

I am using the Spring Boot Actuator and I can see this in the Hal Browser:

```
"DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration": [
  {
    "condition": "OnClassCondition",
    "message": "@ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager'"
  }
],
"DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration": [
  {
    "condition": "OnBeanCondition",
    "message": "@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'psmDataSource', 'dataSource'"
  }
],
"DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration#transactionManager": [
  {
    "condition": "OnBeanCondition",
    "message": "@ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans"
  }
],
"DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.TransactionManagementConfiguration": [
  {
    "condition": "OnBeanCondition",
    "message": "@ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans"
  }
],
```

I'm assuming that this means that a Transaction Manager has been successfully configured, so I'm not sure why the transactions aren't being rolled back.Is

Any ideas?

DAO Interface:

```
public interface IContestService {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)    
    ContestDTO create(final ElectionEventDTO electionEvent, final ElectionDTO election, final ContestDTO contest, final PollingPlaceDTO pollingPlace, final List<CandidateDTO> candidates);
}
```

DAO Implemtnation:

```
@Override
public ContestDTO create(final ElectionEventDTO electionEvent, final ElectionDTO election, final ContestDTO contest, final PollingPlaceDTO pollingPlace, final List<CandidateDTO> candidates) {

    if(electionEvent.getId() == null) {
        getElectionEventService().save(electionEvent);
    }

    if(election.getId() == null) {
        election.setElectionEvent(electionEvent);
        getElectionService().save(election);
    }

    if(election != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Rolling back");
    }
    contest.setElection(election);
    getContestDAO().save(contest);

    getCandidateService().save(candidates);

    /**
     * Return the contest
     */
    return contest;
}
```

application.properties:

```
logging.file=cm-web.log
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

countdb.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/countdb
countdb.datasource.username=root
countdb.datasource.password=pass123
countdb.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

psm.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/psm
psm.datasource.username=root
psm.datasource.password=password
psm.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Shows us a code example

Comment: can you add your application.properties?

Comment: In your @SpringBootConfiguration class.. do you have some extra configuration regarding entity managers / transaction managers?

Comment: Which proxy are you using JDK or CGLIB? In case of CGLIB this won't work as the interface annotation are not inherited.

Comment: Maciej, I have no additional configuration regarding entity managers or transaction managers

Comment: For anyone scratching there head why it is not working on throwing exception @Transactional(rollbackFor = YourException.class), this is spring @Transaction, not javax. This would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@Transactional` annotation is on an interface (which arguably is a bad idea, why would you want such implementation-specific details to show up in your contract?). Spring Boot uses CGLIB proxy by default so you simply don't have any transaction at all as far as I can see.

You can add `@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=false)` on your `@SpringBootApplication` to confirm this is the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that the @Transactional annotation was on an interface. Putting @Transactional annotations on an interface is something I prefer to do and I have done for some time, however as this was a Spring Boot app it didn't work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.